# ANSI NULLS and the ON clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #address (ID int IDENTITY, housenumber varchar(30), street varchar(30), town varchar(30), county varchar(30), postcode varchar(30), primary key (id))
insert into  #address (housenumber,street,town,county,postcode) values ('1', 'The Street', 'Lincoln', null, 'LN21AA')
insert into  #address (housenumber,street,town,county,postcode) values ('1', 'The Street', 'Lincoln', null, 'LN21AA')
insert into  #address (housenumber,street,town,county,postcode) values ('1', 'The Street', 'Lincoln', 'Lincolnshire', 'LN21AA')
```

and the SQL below:

```
   select #address .id as masterid, address2.id as childid  from #address inner join #address as address2 on 
    #address.housenumber=address2.housenumber and #address.street=address2.street
    and #address.town=address2.town
    and #address.county=address2.county
    and #address.postcode=address2.postcode
where #address.id<address2.id
```

I am trying to identify duplicates.

The 'County' is null sometimes and is not null others.  The query above returns no rows.

I have tried this command:

```
set ansi_nulls off
```

However, it makes no difference.  I realise I can do this:

```
select #address .id as masterid, address2.id as childid  from #address inner join #address as address2 on 
#address.housenumber=address2.housenumber and #address.street=address2.street
and #address.town=address2.town
and ((#address.county=address2.county) or (#address.county is null and address2.county is null))
and #address.postcode=address2.postcode
```

However, I am interested to know why setting ansi nulls to off allows you to do this:

```
select * from #address where county=null
```

which returns two rows.  However, my first query returns no rows when ANSI NULLs is off.  Why does ANSI NULLS have no affect on the ON clause.

I have spend 20 minutes Googling this, however I have not found my answer.
    where #address.id

Comment: According to ANSI, NULL values are never equal to anything else.

Comment: Who cares? Turning off ANSI NULLs is deprecated anyway. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: I have finally realised what this paragraph in the documentation is referring to "SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison.". The second sentence says that the setting has no effect. The first sentence is deceptive since it's actually when ANSI_NULLS is **OFF** that you'll observe a discrepancy between the setting and system behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *identify* duplicates by using `group by`.  The following returns the ids when there are two values:

```
select housenumber, street, town, country postcode, count(*) as cnt,
       min(a.id) as masterid, max(a.id) as childid 
from #address a
group by housenumber, street, town, country postcode
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Getting all ids for a given address would require additional joins or funky string aggregations.